# Cannot access mapped NAS from within stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

Any trouble-shooting ideas or general suggestions are greatly appreciated.
I have a stored procedure that maps a NAS file location to my local machine (using XP_CMDSHELL) and iterates through the DBs in the current instance, executing a backup for each. This SP works fine when executed manually in SSMS and providing the parameters via the “Execute Stored Procedure…” interface.

However, when I execute the SP from a C# program, connect to the DB instance and execute an SqlCommand object which contains the SP name and additional required parameters to perform the NAS mapping, the SP fails on each iteration of the backup attempt stating the backup path cannot be found.

So far I’ve confirmed that the correct information is being passed from C# to the SQL connection via the command object. The error information returned from SQL to C# indicates that the SQL Backup is looking for the right directory. Also I’ve confirmed that when I pass the drive parameters for the local drive (e.g. ‘C:’ with a backup folder of ‘Temp’), the SP works as expected.

I am about 95% certain that the mapped drive is not being seen by the SP when it is executed from my program and I am just about as certain there is a way to set the execution of the SP so it will see that mapped drive; I just don’t know how. I’ve even gone so far as to set a WAITFOR DELAY of 25 seconds after executing XP_CMDSHELL.
Any and all help is appreciated. Here is a copy of the stored procedure:

```
USE [nameofdb]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure to backup databases    Script Date: 1/31/2020 9:12:54 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[BackupDatabases]
    @networkPath [varchar](80), -- The Network path to be mapped for backup
    @backupFolder [varchar](60), -- The folder at the Network path to be backed up to
    @driveLetter [varchar](2) -- The Drive letter to be used for Network path mapping
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @dbName varchar(50) = '' -- The DB Name to be backed up
    DECLARE @path varchar(256) -- path of backup files
    DECLARE @fileName varchar(256) -- filename for backup
    DECLARE @fileDate varchar(20) -- used for file name
    DECLARE @netusePath varchar (100) -- used for full connect path
    SET @netusePath = concat('net use ', @driveLetter, ' ', @networkPath)
    EXEC XP_CMDSHELL @netusePath
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:25'
    SELECT @fileDate = CONVERT(varchar(20),GETDATE(),112)
    DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases
        WHERE name NOT IN ('master','model','msdb','tempdb','ReportServer','ReportServerTempDB')
        OPEN db_cursor
            FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @dbName
            WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
                SET @fileName = @driveLetter + '\' + @backupFolder + '\' + @dbName + '_' + @fileDate + '.BAK'
                BACKUP DATABASE @dbName TO DISK = @fileName
                FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @dbName
            END
        CLOSE db_cursor
    DEALLOCATE db_cursor
    SET @netusePath = 'net use /delete ' + @driveLetter
    EXEC XP_CMDSHELL @netusePath
END
```

Comment: My best guess at the problem here would be that when you run the SP manually and are logged onto the server, the drive is mapped in the context of your user account, which won't happen if you execute the SP remotely from a program of any kind. You might have to alter the SET @netusePath line to include a username or password for the drive mapping, or give the computer account for the SQL server permissions to access the network path hosted on the NAS.

Comment: Are you using the UNC path, or the name of the mapped drive? You should be using the former.

Comment: @LordPupazz The program is running under the same user account as when I'm logged into SSMS.

Comment: @Larnu I'm mapping to a drive letter using the UNC path. Are you recommending that I map to and just use the UNC? Credentials are required for the mapping of the NAS.

Comment: Yes, definately use UNC. What you have mapped, and what the SQL Server's Service account has mapped can be completely different. Always use UNC paths.

Comment: @Larnu, The UNC idea seems promising. I'm getting execution timeout expired now which may just have to do with some of the changes I've made. I'm going to debug to find out what's going on there. Next posting may not be until early next week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to @Larnu who pointed me in the direction to use UNC paths instead of drive letters.
When backing up to a UNC path, my SqlCommand object kept timing out but the fix to that was to: First, remove the line WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:25' from the SPROC (that was eating up the SqlCommand timeout anyway). Second, I set the value of SqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 180.
Between those two changes, the program and SPROC are now working together nicely.

Answer (score 0):

> I am about 95% certain that the mapped drive is not being seen by the
>   SP

You could create a test procedure (called from within the app) and check if the drive is mapped correctly and if the backup folder exists (capture the output of dir)

```
..............

SET @netusePath = concat('net use ', @driveLetter, ' ', @networkPath)
EXEC XP_CMDSHELL @netusePath
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:25'

--check if the share is mapped
declare @checkdrive varchar(50) = 'dir ' + @driveLetter;
exec xp_cmdshell @checkdrive;

--check if the backup folder exists
declare @checkfolder varchar(50) = 'dir ' + @driveLetter + '\' + @backupFolder ;
exec xp_cmdshell @checkfolder;

 .....................
```

Comment: Thanks. I've considered that and will probably need to go there. For now, I'm working with the UNC suggestion Larnu made in an above comments. When I get resolution (one way or another) I will post.